# Technical Pictures of Prussian Cannons

Tags: weapons, napoleonic-wars, artillery

For my research I found these wonderful pictures showing all artillery weapons used during the Seven Years War.

[image]
http://crogges7ywarmies.blogspot.de/2012/09/prussian-7yw-artillery-scale-drawings.html

Although I have checked all avaiable references I could find, I haven't found equivalent pictures of the Prussian artillery used during the Napoleonic Wars.

Is someone in possession of a book that could deliver these information (technical measurements are the most important facts here, but an image would make the 3D recreation much more easier)

Answer (score 5):

Here are some French artillery of Napoleonic armies technical drawings and photos. The site is in Russian but
the drawings are copied from some French originals. Inscriptions on drawings are in French.
The Russians have a huge collection of them (captured in 1812-15) on display in Kremlin.

http://wars175x.narod.ru/fr_art01.html

http://wars175x.narod.ru/fr_art02.html

Here is a book on British artillery of Napoleonic times:

http://vive.moy.su/shop/478/desc/british-napoleonic-field-artillery

And an article with some technical drawings and further references:

http://www.napoleon-series.org/military/Warof1812/2009/Issue12/c_Artillery.html

Here is a Russian book on 1812 artillery (Russian and French). It has few technical drawings (some of them copies of the French ones, others made by the author, many photos, and a lot of various technical data:

http://flibusta.is/b/306187/read

Comment: This doesn't answer the given question, which was clearly asking for Prussian cannons.

Comment: @KillingTime - The title seems to, but the question itself  (graphics aside)  does not have the word "Prussian" in it anywhere.

Comment: @T.E.D. The title *seems to*? How much more explict does it have to be? Given that his previous (almost certainly related) question was about Prussian Artillery, I think it's safe to say this one is about Prussian Cannon. If it wasn't, why would he put "Prussian" in the title and include an example of an earlier Prussian cannon?

Comment: The question indeed did not specify whether it is about Prussian cannon or about all of them of Napoleonic era. But the search on the web was relatively easy and I suppose that Prussian ones can be found as well.